# Join 2 list by text and add value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to transfer the value in brackets from the second list to the first. I tried to do this:

```
$('#views-exposed-form-cat-watch-block .form-type-radio label.option').each(function(){
    var a = this;
    $('#block-views-tags-block .views-field-name a').each(function(){
        var b = this;
        if($(a).text().indexOf(b)!=-1){         
            var c = $(b).closest('.views-row').find('.views-field-nid .field-content').text();
            $(a).after('<span>'+c+'</span>');
        }
    });
});
```

This is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/0xm6xzLb/1/ It should looks like this:

```
Word (4)
Word2 (1)
Word3 (2)

Word 
(4)
Word2 
(1)
Word3 
(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had yours working. The only thing I changed from the version you provided with the following line:

```
if($(a).text() == $(b).text())
```

The issue with the version you provided was `b` is a DOM element, so `indexof` will always return -1. After converting `b` to text everything will work. The next thing you'll notice is because you are using index of, the first item `Word` appears as a substring in all three items. To bypass this, I just set it so that the text must be equal which prevents this overlap.

```
$(function() {
    $('#views-exposed-form-cat-watch-block .form-type-radio label.option').each(function(){
        var a = this;
        $('#block-views-tags-block .views-field-name a').each(function(){
            var b = this;
            if($(a).text() == $(b).text()){
                var c = $(b).closest('.grid-1-4').find('.views-field-nid .field-content').text();
                $(a).after('<span>'+c+'</span>');
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```